# onclick event in jade

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, click, pug

I'm trying to make a simple alert event in jade, but its not working somehow, don't really know whats the problem, maybe you guys can find it?

Code:
PS: you can ignore the socket.io code

```
html
head
script(src='jquery-1.7.1.js')
  script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
script
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3002/add_users');
  socket.on("update", function(message) {
  console.log("update: ", message)
  });
  $(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    alert("hej");
  });
  });   
body
.container
.content
    header.page-header
       h1 Welcome
    .row

            form(action='/', method='post')
                fieldset
                        label(for="name") Namn
                            input(type="text", size="30", name="name", required="required")
                            button Save
            ul
                li <a href="/users">User list</a>
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered page as well?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with Jade myself, but isn't your `script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')` indented incorrectly?

If it is, I assume that would cause the `socket.io.js` not to load correctly. And if it doesn't load correctly, then your javascript execution would break at `io.connect`, before binding the jQuery DOMReady listener.

Comment: There's nothing to do with the socket.io code as i mentioned, i just want a simple alert message. Even i delete the socket.io code its not giving a single popup alert.

Comment: @nihulus: even unrelated code could break your execution, though, if there's a problem with it. Do you mind posting the rendered output?

Comment: @nihulus To expand on David's answer... check the generated output and see if your socket.io script is being loaded within the `<script src='jquery'></script>` tag. This shouldn't be indented more than your other script tags.  Also, I would move the socket.io stuff into your jquery ready function or after the body tag because that could be executing before the script is loaded and a js error would prevent the `.click` function from executing.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `$("button").click()` code executes before DOM is loaded. You should explicitly pass your function to `$.ready()`.

PS: I know that passing a function to jQuery (what you do) should be the same as doing `$.ready()` but I had the same kind of problem before.

Comment: I think passing a function to the `$()` function has been a shortcut for `$.ready()` since about jquery 1.4.